# Changing ID3 tags of an mp3 - album art

Tags: php, tags, mp3, id3

I would like to change the album art of an mp3 when it is downloaded. Users upload their songs and when fans download the song - it must have an attached album art

I use PHP as a programming language.

Comment: check out: http://php.net/manual/en/book.id3.php

Comment: @anditpainsme It doesn't look like it supports APIC.

Comment: @NullUserException My bad. Check out http://www.getid3.org/